# Linked Oracle View not refreshing in MS Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access, oracle11g

I'm facing an issue when refreshing linked oracle views in MS Access.
I have a linked oracle view in an Access Database. I recently updated the oracle view at the backend to include new fields. 
Now, I tried refreshing the linked oracle view in the MS Access Database file using the 'Linked Table Manager'. But I still see only the old view structure, and not the new structure with the updated new fields. I tried creating a new linked view pointing to the oracle view. The newly created linked view also has only the previous structure of the view and the newly included fields are not seen. I recreated the DNS ODBC file and tried too. 
Has anyone ever faced such a scenario? Does any cache or registry have to be cleared to truly refresh the linked oracle views? Kindly help me with this issue.

Update:
I found something upon further analysis. I mirrored the oracle view into a test view and linked it to Access. I found that the fields were missing here too. Now, I reduced the number of fields in the view to about 20 fields, and repeated the process. This time, I was able to see the new fields. I suppose the new fields are not showing up due to a limitation in the number of fields. Is there a setting where I can increase the number of fields that are brought into Access from a linked table? My original Oracle view has about 538 fields.

Comment: This would be very unusual. Are you sure your linked view in Access points to the same database / instance where you changed the view?

Comment: The database is the same database. I found something upon further analysis. I mirrored the oracle view into a test view and linked it to Access. I found that the fields were missing here too. Now, I reduced the number of fields in the view to about 20 fields, and repeated the process. This time, I was able to see the new fields. I suppose the new fields are not showing up due to a limitation in the number of fields. Is there a setting where I can increase the number of fields that are brought into Access from a linked table? My original Oracle view has about 538 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of fields in a table (a view is linked as a table) is 255. See [Access specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c).

Show your views sql, as this seems to be a database structure issue. Usually you don't need that amout of fields.

To work around, create views on the view, with max 255 fields to display them.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Yes, that is the reason for the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you improve your questions formatting (paragraphs), you'll get a vote! For tipps read [ask] and related.